# I have a problem with Android Studio 3.3 Autocomplete code

Tags: java, android, android-studio

when I wrote the code with android studio automatically generated me the code connected now does not do anything. I'll explain...
when I was writing for example

```
<Button
```

in automatic android studio I was generating this

```
<Button
  android:layout_width=""
  android:layout_height=""
```

and I changed the values ​​... now it does not do anything anymore ... if I write

```
<Button
```

android studio generates this ...

```
<Button />
```

How can I solve? I tried both "Invalidates caches / Restart" and then I also deactivated "Prower Save Mode"

Thank you very much

Comment: Verify you have all plugins and libraries up-to-date. Also check in Preference -> Code Completion options to be enabled.

Comment: I did not find any preferences menu or options